# Jquery carousel with two row indicators

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel, bootstrap-carousel

Looking for a Jquery Carousel plugin or ideas how can I do something like this.

- Indicator cat1

  - indicator image 1
  - indicator image 2
  - ....
- Indicator cat2

  - indicator image 1
  - indicator image 2
  - ...

Carousel

[image]

Comment: I self find solution - it's bootstrap tabs + bootstrap carousel - indicators as cols with images